# "~" symbol created automatically after running project with service worker

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

My project is a simple login page. I am using asp.net core with MVC.

Everything was working well and I wanted to add service worker to my project. I followed the known steps. Add a *manifest.json* file in **wwwroot**, fill it correctly and add this function *services.AddProgressiveWebApp();* after *services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);*.

When others do these steps, service worker works properly. When I run it (IIS Express), service worker produces an error: "*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.*"

Then I realized this thing: *https://localhost:44331/~/serviceworker*.
The ~ symbol is created automatically and I am not knowing how to remove it.
The following *https://localhost:44331/serviceworker* works.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved.

I updated the version from v1.0.42 to v.1.0.33 and it worked.

v1.0.42 has a bug.

Comment: v1.0.42 of *what*? [This package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.PWA)? Did you check the project's repo on [Github](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.ServiceWorker)? If there are bugs, you'll find them in the `Issues` along with workarounds

Comment: This has been reported [here](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.ServiceWorker/issues/36)

Comment: Yes. Thank you.